# How to generate a new log file containing the MAC adress based on pihole.log which didn't contain it by default

Tags: command-line, networking, text-processing, log

I have a `/var/log/pihole.log` that contains lines like these:

```
Nov 29 18:49:33 dnsmasq[13568]: query[AAAA] firebaselogging-pa.googleapis.com from 192.168.0.10
Nov 29 18:49:33 dnsmasq[13568]: query[A] firebaselogging-pa.googleapis.com from 192.168.0.10
Nov 29 18:49:41 dnsmasq[13568]: query[AAAA] app-measurement.com from 192.168.0.10
Nov 29 18:49:41 dnsmasq[13568]: query[A] app-measurement.com from 192.168.0.10
Nov 29 18:49:57 dnsmasq[13568]: query[AAAA] in.treasuredata.com from 192.168.0.10
Nov 29 18:49:57 dnsmasq[13568]: query[A] in.treasuredata.com from 192.168.0.10
```

`arp -a` gives me the match between MAC and IP:

```
root@raspberrypi:/var/log# arp -n
Address                  HWtype  HWaddress           Flags Mask            Iface
192.168.0.81             ether   c8:5b:76:e1:3c:6f   C                     wlan0
192.168.0.136            ether   14:ab:c5:09:de:81   C                     wlan0
192.168.0.207            ether   68:c6:3a:a2:f4:e1   C                     wlan0
192.168.0.213            ether   60:01:94:70:e9:9c   C                     wlan0
192.168.0.67             ether   8c:fe:57:51:1d:51   C                     wlan0
```

I want to generate a new live `pihole2.log` file with the MAC at the end. Her is my script:

```bsh
tail -f /var/log/pihole.log|grep "query" |grep -v "<name"| awk 'NR==1{print $0,"MIME_type"; next}
        { cmd = "/var/log/nico.sh " $8
          cmd | getline result
          close(cmd)
          print $1,$2,$3,$6,$8, result }'
```

I use `nico.sh` to perform the `arp` search. `nico.sh` contains:

```bsh
#!/bin/sh
param=$1
cmd="$(arp -n|awk '$1 == x {print $3}' x=$param)"
echo $cmd
```

The script doesn't progress while `pihole.log` is showing additional lines.

Comment: what version of OS are you using?

Answer (score 0):

This Bash single-liner works for me:

```bsh
tail -f /var/log/pihole.log | while read line ; do echo -n "$line" ; ip=$(echo "$line" | awk '{print $NF}') ; mac=$(arp -n | grep '^'$ip' ' | awk '{print $3}') ; [ "$mac" = "" ] && echo " xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx" || echo " $mac" ; done >> /var/log/pihole2.log
```

or in multiline form:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
tail -f /var/log/pihole.log | while read line ; do
  echo -n "$line"
  ip=$(echo "$line" | awk '{print $NF}')
  mac=$(arp -n | grep '^'$ip' '|  awk '{print $3}')
  [ "$mac" = "" ] && echo " xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx" || echo " $mac"
done >> /var/log/pihole2.log
```